# converting from string to unsigned char * and vice versa

Tags: c++, encryption, casting

I have two functions: 1. encryption (string text, string key) and 2. decryption (string text, string key). these functions encrypt/decrypt text under key . I use openssl library and functions:EVP_EncryptUpdate and EVP_DecryptUpdate the input arguments of these two functions are (EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx, unsigned char *out, int *outl, const unsigned char *in, int inl). my functions are below and the output is :
"Hello world\x5\x5\x5\x5\x5"
which should be "Hello world"
i suppose there is something wrong with castings.

```
std::string encrypt(std::string text, std::string k){   
    const unsigned char  *plaintext=(const unsigned char*) text.c_str();
    const unsigned char  *key=(const unsigned char*) k.c_str();
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;
    int len;
    int plaintext_len=strlen((const char *)plaintext);
    int ciphertext_len=plaintext_len+256;
    unsigned char * ciphertext=new unsigned char[ciphertext_len];
    
    /* Create and initialise the context */
    if(!(ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new()))
       handleErrors();

    /*
     * Initialise the encryption operation.
     */
    if(1 != EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, key, NULL))
        handleErrors();
    /*
     * Provide the message to be encrypted, and obtain the encrypted output.
     * EVP_EncryptUpdate can be called multiple times if necessary
     */
    if(1 != EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, ciphertext, &len, plaintext, plaintext_len))
        handleErrors();
    ciphertext_len = len;
    /*
     * Finalise the encryption. Further ciphertext bytes may be written at
     * this stage.
     */
    if(1 != EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(ctx, ciphertext + len, &len))
        handleErrors();
    ciphertext_len += len;

    /* Clean up */
   EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);

    
    std::string cipherteststring=(char const* )ciphertext ;

    delete []ciphertext;
    return cipherteststring;    
}

std::string decrypt(std::string text, std::string k)
{   
    
    const unsigned char  *ciphertext=(const unsigned char*)text.c_str();
    const unsigned char  *key=(const unsigned char*) k.c_str();
    int ciphertext_len=strlen((const char *)ciphertext);
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;
    int len;
    int plaintext_len=ciphertext_len;
    unsigned char *decryptedtext=new unsigned char[plaintext_len];

    /* Create and initialise the context */
    if(!(ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new()))
        handleErrors();

    /*
     * Initialise the decryption operation.
     */
    if(1 != EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, key, NULL))
       handleErrors();

    /*
     * Provide the message to be decrypted, and obtain the plaintext output.
     * EVP_DecryptUpdate can be called multiple times if necessary.
     */
    if(1 != EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, decryptedtext, &len, ciphertext, ciphertext_len))
       handleErrors();

    /* Clean up */
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
    //std::string plaintextstring( reinterpret_cast< char const* >(decryptedtext) ) ;
    std::string plaintextstring=(char const*)decryptedtext;
    decryptedtext[plaintext_len] = '\0';    
    delete []decryptedtext;
    return plaintextstring;
}
int main (){
std::string key ="01234567890123456789012345678901";
    std::string plaintext ="Hello world";
    std::string encrypted;
    std::string decrypted;
    std::string decryptedhexstr;
    encrypted=encrypt (plaintext,key);
    decrypted = decrypt(encrypted, key);
    cout<<decrypted;
return 0;
}``
```

Comment: If you do this right there should be hardly, if any,  'castings', so that's probably the first problem. It find it odd also that you're using cbc with no IV.

Comment: Looks like an error dealing with the length of the cipher text vs the length of the plain text. You are using a block cipher. So the cipher text length will be a multiple of 16 bytes.

Comment: This: `std::string cipherteststring=(char const* )ciphertext` is also a recipe for failure. there is absolutely non guarantee the resulting encipherment will not have embedded nullchars. If you want a "string" you need to encode it using a method like base64, hex, etc. I'm not convinced you need one, but if you do, there's a problem there too.

Comment: `decryptedtext[plaintext_len] = '\0'` writes out of bounds, so the behaviour of your program is undefined. (There is also no point in doing that just before the `delete`, but *after* building a `std::string` from it.)

Comment: decryptedtext[plaintext_len] = '\0' Add a NULL terminator. We are expecting printable text, but by deleting this line nothing gonna change.

Comment: when i print the result everything is correct but the value of the result is what I showed.

Comment: It *would* add a terminator if it weren't writing outside the array, but it would also have no observable effect since you delete that array in the next line. You need to null-terminate *before* you create the `std::string` from it, and the last valid index is `plaintext_len-1`.

Comment: I'd probably take [a different approach](https://godbolt.org/z/8djbfa6n9). securing with a string passphrase should run through an expensive expansion algorithm like PBKDF2 or bcrypt, and including salting to ensure unique output on each encryption, even with the same passphrase and plaintext.